# How can I set the default page in IIS to a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis, iis-6, startup

We have an MVC application that is accessed from two separate websites. The default website is fine, however how can I setup the second site to startup in a specific Controller?

Our default site is `www.mysite.com`, and we'd like to add a second IIS site for the header `www.subdomain.mysite.com` that should take users to `www.subdomain.mysite.com/controller`

But how can I tell IIS to startup `www.mysubdomain.mysite.com` with the specific controller action `mycontroller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a value to my `AppSettings` in web.config, and adjusting the default route of the application based on that value.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var defaultController = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultController"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultController))
        defaultController = "Home";

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = defaultController, action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    ...
}
```

This allows me to host any number of IIS sites that can each start with a different controller in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider configuring URL Rewrite so that requests to `www.mysubdomain.mysite.com` get seen as requests to `www.mysubdomain.mysite.com/controller`.

You could use [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).

> Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter, aka IIRF, is a small, FREE, easy to use,
>   URL rewriting ISAPI filter. It combines a good price (free!) with good
>   features. It is fast and powerful. It works on IIS 6.0, and later.

Comment: I really want to avoid using a URL Rewrite tool if possible.... the web server hosting the site has a bunch of other sites on it as well, and we've had problems with URL Rewrite tools in the past.